# SQLAlchemy utils drop database statement cannot be used inside a user transaction

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

I have the code below which fails with the message

```
from sqlalchemy_utils.functions import database_exists, create_database, drop_database

url = f'mssql+pymssql://user:secret_password@db_host/my_database?charset=utf8'
if database_exists(url):
    drop_database(url)
create_database(url)
```

Error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymssql.OperationalError)
>   (574, b'DROP DATABASE statement cannot be used inside a user
>   transaction.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL
>   Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n') E   [SQL: DROP
>   DATABASE my_database] E

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Not sure what I'm doing wrong - examples online show this as valid code. There is no state - I've executed the above in a fresh ipython session.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work with sqlalchemy-utils, but I could get it to work with just sqlalchemy and executing sql.

The key seems to be telling the *engine* to use *autocommit*.

For example, the following will generate the same error that you are experiencing:

```
db_master = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://server/master?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')

db_master.execute('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ' + destination_db)
db_master.execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + destination_db)
```

of:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000',
>   '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]DROP
>   DATABASE statement cannot be used inside a user transaction. (574)
>   (SQLExecDirectW)')

However, adding the autocommit option to the engine creation as per below removes the error and DROPs and CREATEs the database 'destination_db' as expected:

```
db2_master = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://server/master?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0', connect_args = {'autocommit':True})

db2_master.execute('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ' + destination_db)
db2_master.execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + destination_db)
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I believe I created the engine like so and still got the error but I had so many permutations that perhaps I did something different: engine = create_engine(self.config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, connect_args={'autocommit': True}, isolation_level='AUTOCOMMIT')

Comment: @t_warsop, why did that work for you? If I add `engine.execute('COMMIT')` after each statement, it fails, but `autocommit: True` works.